# How to remove list of lists based on a given list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I have two lists like below.

```
l=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B','C']]
x=[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]
```

I want to remove the list from l ,which isn't present in list  of tuples in x.

for example `l ['B','c']` list is present but we don't `(B,C)` combination in x so we need to remove i.e B,C both elements not presented any single tuple in X.
 my expected output will be:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit about the rules? For instance, `x` does not contain either `('B', 'C')` or `('A', 'B', 'C')`, yet somehow you want to remove one and keep the other?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MartinFrodl Maybe because both `'B'` and `'C'` are *related* to `'A'` through `('A', 'B')` & `('A', 'C')` tuples respectively? Just guessing though..

Comment: @Ev. Kounis ,ya your correct .@Martin Frodl  'B' and 'C' are related to 'A' through ('A', 'B') & ('A', 'C'). the variable's  presented in x  tuples should present l. for example l is ['A', 'B', 'C']  .x is  ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C') in our case (A,B ) presented in l and (a,c) presented .at lest  one is presented also fine. but in case of ['B','C'] no tuple in X all variable nothing so we need to remove ,['B','C'] from my final list .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a condtional [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> [l_ for l_ in l if any(all(e in l_ for e in x_) for x_ in x)]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Although all of the above work, One is considerably faster.
Below is the measured time in seconds of each solution for 100 000 runs.

- schwobaseggl:  0.80720812
- long_for_loop:  0.7031608010000001
- shlomiLan 0.24393211999999997
- Miklos_Horvath 0.683809444 (has not been converted back to list)

As seen above shlomiLan is almost 3 times as fast as any other solution.
code used to get the results can ben seen here:

```
import timeit
setup = """
l = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B','C']]
x = [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]"""

schwobaseggl = "[l_ for l_ in l if any(all(e in l_ for e in x_) for x_ in x)]"

long_for_loop = '''
c = []
for l_ in l:
    d = []
    for x_ in x:
        a = []
        for e in x_:
            if e in l_:
                a.append(True)
            else:
                a.append(False)
                break
        if all(a):
            d.append(True)
    if any(d):
        c.append(l_)
'''

shlomiLan = """new_list = []
for i in l:
    # Must use a flag, because we have 2 items that are the same in l (['A', 'B', 'C'])
    # so can't use append if i not new_list
    is_i_added = False
    for z in x:
        if is_i_added:
            continue

        j_not_in_i = False
        for j in z:
            if j not in i:
                j_not_in_i = True

        if not j_not_in_i:
            new_list.append(i)
            is_i_added = True"""

miklos_Horvath = "l = list(filter(lambda m: any(all(e in m for e in y) for y in x), l))"

a = timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=schwobaseggl, number=100000)
b = timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=long_for_loop, number=100000)
c = timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=shlomiLan, number=100000)
d = timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=miklos_Horvath, number=100000)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is to complex for a one-liner.

```
new_list = []
for i in l:
    # Must use a flag, because we have 2 items that are the same in l (['A', 'B', 'C'])
    # so can't use append if i not new_list
    is_i_added = False
    for z in x:
        if is_i_added:
            continue

        j_not_in_i = False
        for j in z:
            if j not in i:
                j_not_in_i = True

        if not j_not_in_i:
            new_list.append(i)
            is_i_added = True

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter like this:

```
l=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B','C']]
x=[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]

l = list(filter(lambda m: any(all(e in m for e in y) for y in x), l))

print(l)
```

Comment: It is a little bit slower than the list comprehesion what schowbaseggl wrote but if you dont need to convert the filter back to list it will be faster :)