# pyspark Udf is not working as expected when apply map transformation with broadcast?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, user-defined-functions

I have a two list like below

```python
l=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B','C'],['B']]
x=[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]
```

I want to remove from the list of lists `l`, all elements that do not contain all of the elements in any of the `tuple`s in the list `x`. In other words, there should be at least one `tuple` in `x` for which all of the all items that tuple are present in the elements of `l`.

Based on my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53665603/how-to-remove-list-of-lists-based-on-a-given-list-of-tuples), I was given the following solution in python:

```python
print([l_ for l_ in l if any(all(e in l_ for e in x_) for x_ in x)])
```

which yields the desired output of:

```python
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Now I am trying to replicate the same operation with a pyspark `rdd`, but I am not getting the expected result.

This is what I tried:

```python
rddsort=sc.parallelize(l)
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(x)

def flist(unique_product_List,x):
    filter_list = [
        l_ for l_ in unique_product_List 
        if any(all(e in l_ for e in x_) for x_ in x)
    ]

    return filter_list

rddsort=rddsort.map(lambda flist(x[0],broadcastVar.value)) 
print(rddsort.collect())
```

I am getting a list of empty lists as the result:

```python
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

But my expected result should be the same as above.

Comment: You don't need to pass the broadcast variable to the `map` function. By broadcasting it, it's already available on each machine as a read-only variable.

Comment: The problem is that you're doing the list comprehension over `unique_product_List` inside your `map` function. What do you think that's iterating over? It's not the rows in your `rdd` as you think- it's the elements in each row.

Comment: can please help me .How can I resolve this Issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need a filter on the rdd (not a map). The filter would check for a condition on each row and remove those that don't match. Here the condition is that row value (list _l = l[0]) should have of all elements in of one of lists in x.

```
l=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B','C'],['B']]
x=[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]
rddsort=sc.parallelize(l)

rddsort=rddsort.filter(lambda l_: any(all(e in l_ for e in x_) for x_ in x)) 
print(rddsort.collect())
```

Output

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B']]
```

Update:
With broadcast variable in a function:

```
l=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B'],['B','C'],['B']]
x=[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C')]
rddsort=sc.parallelize(l)
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(x)

def flist(row):
    filter_flag = any(all(e in l_ for e in x_) for x_ in broadcastVar.value)
    return filter_flag

rddsort=rddsort.filter(flist) 
print(rddsort.collect())
```

Comment: Hi thanks  for reply, but i want to use  broadcast variable  as per my question,please help on this.above suggested solution we are not using.

Comment: Updated the answer which uses broadcast variable in a function